# Is there a way i can pass my FirstActivity Context to my SecondActivity Context or any Other Activity to make changes in my First Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity, android-context

I have my FirstActivity with me which has widgets/Components clubbed inside the FirstActivity (toggle btn, check box etc.), all of them are open to changes (non-static.).

Now I start SecondActivity which performs some tasks and moves to ThirdActivity

My question is, how can i pass the Context of my FirstActivity to SecondActivity so that I can make the UI changes in the FirstActivity depending on the results of SecondActivity and then can simply move to the ThirdActivity?

Can we pass Context of one Activity to another Activity.
I have tried StartActivityForResult() and i dont think to use it here.

what am i missing here, how can i access the components/widgets of another activity from second activity ?

**Here I have created a Class to hold my FirstActivity Context and I use My SecondActivity to Fetch the Same Context entered, it works this way, but is this the only way we can do it? do we have anything more DIRECT.?**

```
    public  class ContextHolder {
static Context c;

static void setContext(Context context){
    c=context;
}

static Context getContext(){
    return c;
}
}
```

Comment: Why change the Ui of an activity that you will not display ? Save the result of your second activity somewhere and update the first one in its onResume() method

Comment: Why do i think that this would increase some storage( moreover maintaining the stored objects )and relatively a little more processing on every call to onResume() , I believe better way would be changing the UI of the FirstActivity at the very moment when I am in SecondActivity , what do you suggest?

Comment: As grunk says, create an object and pass it back to your first activity for it to change its content in onResume. Passing the context of each activity round mean that activity is still in memory and every object attached to it. BAD

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to pass the context directly, rather you should be using [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)  to start the second activity, and a combination of [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) in the second activity with [getActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) in the first activity to pass the data back in a bundle, the first activity would then update its own UI and you would also avoid the problems that @grunk and @Blundell mention.